# How to set maxDate in jquery datepicker based on certain value

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to set **maxDate** based on user selection of given input date, suppose if user select today date then the **maxDate** should be set to 3 or 4 days from today or even a week upto max.But i am using the following logic to set **minDate** automatically based on user input selection

```
 $(checkIn).datepicker(
           {
                changeMonth:false,
                changeYear:false,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                minDate:0
           });
           var temp;
           $(checkIn).on("change",function()
           {
               var select = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
               temp=select;
               $(checkOut).datepicker('option','minDate',temp)

           })
```

This logic work fines here but when i am trying to set maxDate based on this logic i am getting certain error here is the code

```
$(checkOut).datepicker({
               changeMonth:false,
                changeYear:false,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                maxDate: new Date($(checkIn).val()) + "1w"
    })
```

When i run this code what happen is if i select today's date for instance it gives correct **maxDate** till upto 7 days but if i again change the date in ***checkIn*** input the maxDate is one day less and thus as i keep selecting forward date ahead from current date a point will come where all the date in ***checkOut*** input are disabled and i cant select any of it.

Comment: Update checkout maxDate the same way you do minDate when a change is made

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the **change** event and use the [beforeShow](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow) callback in order to set the maxDate for the second datepicker like in:

```js
$('#checkIn').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date()));
$('#checkIn').datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: 0,
});

$('#checkOut').datepicker({
    changeMonth:false,
    changeYear:false,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        var minDate = $('#checkIn').datepicker('getDate');
        $('#checkOut').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        var maxDate = new Date(minDate.valueOf());
        maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 7);
        $('#checkOut').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<p>Chack In date: <input type="text" id="checkIn"></p>

<p>Check Out date: <input type="text" id="checkOut"></p>
```